# jQuery Each Loop Not updating HTML in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have a variable `html` that stores HTML:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge1">0</td>
    <td class="nc1">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="charge2">0</td>
    <td class="nc2">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge3">250</td>
    <td class="nc3">0</td>
</tr>
```

Basically I need to add the values for the `td` with the class starting with `charge` to the values for the `td` with the class starting with `nc` and replace the value in the `td` with class starting with `nc` with the sum. The values in both `td`'s in each row could change, so the code needs to be dynamic. So for this example, the resulting HMTL in the variable should be:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge1">0</td>
    <td class="nc1">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="charge2">0</td>
    <td class="nc2">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge3">250</td>
    <td class="nc3">250</td>
</tr>
```

In this example, the only row that actually changes is the third row. The `td` starting with class `nc` now shows `250` instead of the original `0`.

I have to use the variable `html` later in the code with the updated `td` information if it did change.

This is the code that I have, but it's not working:

```
var html = $('#chargetable').html();
console.log(html);
$('[class*=nc]', html).each(function(){
    var ncamount = $(this).html();
    var chargeamount = $(this).parents('tr').find('[class*=charge]').html();
    var totalnc = parseFloat(chargeamount) + parseFloat(ncamount);
    $(this).html(totalnc);
    console.log(chargeamount + ' ' + ncamount + ' ' + totalnc);
});
console.log(html);
```

This is the results of the console's log:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge1">0</td>
    <td class="nc1">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="charge2">0</td>
    <td class="nc2">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge3">250</td>
    <td class="nc3">0</td>
</tr>

0 0 0
0 0 0
250 0 250

<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge1">0</td>
    <td class="nc1">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="charge2">0</td>
    <td class="nc2">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="charge3">250</td>
    <td class="nc3">0</td>
</tr>
```

The html variable isn't being updated, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to update, short of splitting the variable, replacing the `td` with class `nc`, and recreating the `html` variable on each iteration. I'm thinking there's got to be a better way to do this.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you code is that you cannot use html variable in this line 
`$('[class*=nc]', html)`
the second parameter is used to define scope in which jQuery searches for the selector.
So, like `document`,`parent.document`(if its iframe etc..)

If you need the original dom you can use jQuery `.clone()` to store the original dom like this

```
//if you require the original code for later clone it 
var htmlclone = $('#chargetable').clone().html();
console.log(htmlclone);
$('#chargetable [class*=nc]').each(function(){
    var ncamount = $(this).html();
    var chargeamount = $(this).parents('tr').find('[class*=charge]').html();
    var totalnc = parseFloat(chargeamount) + parseFloat(ncamount);
    $(this).html(totalnc);
    console.log(chargeamount + ' ' + ncamount + ' ' + totalnc);
});
console.log(htmlclone);
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z4n7kjcf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var $chargeTable = $("#chargetable");
    var $chargeTableCloned = $chargeTable.clone();
    var $chargeTableRows = $("tr", $chargeTableCloned);

    $.each($chargeTableRows, function(i, $tr){
        var $tdCharge = $("td[class^='charge']", $tr);
        var $tdNc = $("td[class^='nc']", $tr);
        var charge = parseInt($tdCharge.text(), 10);
        var nc = parseInt($tdNc.text(), 10);
        $tdNc.text(charge + nc);
    });

    $chargeTable.after($chargeTableCloned);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ottd9tcv/)